# Regex to capture all different type of attribute values from json response

Tags: regex

Following is the response for which I'm creating regex to capture all attributes with their values.

```
"attributes": {
                "created_time": "2014-09-12",
                "currency": "INR",
                "budget": 381000,
                "price": 12345.50,
                "name": "Untitled",
                "start_time": null,
                "updated_time": "2014-09-12",
                "type": ["ads","share"],
                "type1": [{"ads1","share1"}]
                "tracking_specs": [
                   {
                     "creative": [
                       "682"
                     ],
                     "type": [
                        "dwell"
                     ]
                   }
               }
```

I want attributes and their values separately like:
created_time and 2014-09-12 separately. So that using attributes name, I can create query and then fetch data from DB and match with the attributes values.

The regex I've created is `"([^"]+)"*: ("([^"]+)"|([^"]+).00|([^"]+),)` but it seems incorrect. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The following regex will capture everything in your JSON response:

`"[a-zA-Z_]+": (?:(?:"[a-zA-Z0-9-]+")|(?:[a-zA-Z0-9.[",\]]+))`

If you remove the ?: in the outer parenthesis then you have two capturing groups, like so: `"[a-zA-Z_]+": ((?:"[a-zA-Z0-9-]+")|(?:[a-zA-Z0-9.[",\]]+))` This way you can select (depending on what language you're using) the attributes separately from the values.

I'm not sure why you're using regex with a JSON response as any code that relies on the response will have to already know about all possible fields in the response. However, I'm don't even know what it is you're trying to accomplish. If you're ever having a hard time writing a regex for something, a quick way to get it working is to use one of the many online regex testers, e.g. [this one](https://regex101.com/).

Comment: this regex captures attributes and their values as a whole. I am trying to capture attribute and their values separately.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by separately. Regardless, you can split the result of the regex to suit your needs. E.g. if you wish to have each attribute-value pair as a separate element in a list, then you can perform a split on the comma followed by a newline (",\n") which will give you a list of attribute-value pairs. You can then split each element in that list to separate the attributes from their values by splitting the colon (":"). Again, I'm not quite sure what you're trying to accomplish. It would help if you gave a few more details.

Comment: I want to match data with db so I am trying to create a regex which can fetch data that is attributes and their values separately and then I can use it to fetch it from db.
With the help of your regex, I am able to fetch some data but not all.
Regex - "([^"]+)"*: (?:"([^"]+)"|(?:([a-zA-Z0-9]+)))